# pointer to char changes after opendir() system call

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, opendir

i am currently trying to delete directories from system call using c and i am facing a weird problem. In my `deleteFunction()` after using the `char *  path`  to open the directory. the value of `path` changes

here is part of the code:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void deleteDir(char *path){
    //opening the directory
    printf("BEFORE %s\n",path );
    DIR *p = opendir(path);
    if (p == NULL){
        printf("Directory not Opened!\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    printf("AFTER %s\n",path );
}

void main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    if (argc != 2){
        printf("Not enough Arguments!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //creating the path 
    char * currentDir = getcwd(NULL,0);
    strcat(currentDir,"/");
    strcat(currentDir,argv[1]);
    //deleting the directory
    deleteDir(currentDir);
    exit(0);
}
```

the output produced is:

```
BEFORE /home/tarounen/test/newfolder
AFTER /home/tarounen/test/!�
```

note: i am only taking the directory name as parameter

Comment: `main` returns `int`, not `void`. (That's not the cause of your problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getcwd` function is probably allocating just enough space to hold the current path, so adding more characters with `strcat` overflows the buffer, and results in undefined behavior. Try this

```
char path[MAXPATHLEN];
getcwd( path, MAXPATHLEN );
strcat( path, "/" );
strcat( path, argv[1] );
```

Answer (score 3):

`getcwd` only allocates enough memory to hold the directory when you pass `NULL`.
Concatenating to its result has undefined behaviour.

If you want to use `strcat`, you need to provide your own buffer with enough space:

```
char buffer[MAXPATHLEN] = {0};
if (getcwd(buffer, sizeof(buffer)))
{
    strcat(buffer, "/");
    strcat(buffer, argv[1]);
    deleteDir(buffer);
}
```